# Can I remesh an object including all modifiers?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I appied different modifiers to a text (curve + subdivision). The text is curved now but I want to shift and rotate some of the letters a little bit. This is not possible at the moment because the curve modifier is still there. I want to make a new mesh of the text as is and then finetune some of the single letters. Just like in photoshop where you can merge down all effect to a new layer and keep working from there. thank you!

Comment: Yes you can.  I would make a copy of what I had now before I started, but you can apply the curve modifier and then edit the resulting mesh.

Comment: thank you! how would you apply the modifier? object/transform/ mesh from curve?

Comment: If I understand how you did things, yes.